# Extend partition function and scheme in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning

My SQL Server database includes some tables partitioned by month. The partition scheme and function are set to the 20191201 right limit. My partition scheme uses separate file groups for each partition. I now need to extend these before the end of the year (last partition key on the right is `N'20191231'` and last file group `FG_2_201912`).

**Question #1**: do I need to repeat `ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [PartitionByPeriodScheme] NEXT USED [FG_2_202001];` for each file group until `[FG_2_202012]`? I sure can write a script which will produce the command dynamically but is there any way to add all file groups with one command?

**Question #2**: do I need to repeat `ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitionByPeriodFunction]() SPLIT RANGE 20200131` for each partition key value until `20201231`? Do I really need to split range since there are no data in the last right partition yet? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: FYI: SQL Server 2008 (R2) is now completely unsupported (and has been for several months). It is strongly recommended you consider upgrade paths sooner rather than later.

Comment: did you get answer for your question, I have same problem too!

Comment: apparently there is no other way. i have created a script which produces the statements dynamically and then executed the statements